# Fields getting misplaced in mobile devices

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I have one lightning component placed inside community. it looks good in desktop but in mobile devices when submit button is clicked without filling any of the fields then validation is fired and fields get misaligned as shown in the below image. Please help me in making them responsive.

When Validation is fired:-

[image]

Normal VIew:-

[image]

CSS code:-

```
.THIS .FirstName{
    display:block;
    line-height: 20px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width:45%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.THIS .LastName{
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 45%;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.THIS .Email{
    display:block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 95%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Let me inform you that i am getting all fields in list so i cannot apply lightning design to each of the fields or place them inside a div and then apply bootstrap.

This is code in lightning component

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    {!v.formFields}   
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you *can* apply SLDS to each of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am getting list not individual fields how would i apply slds to each one of them

Comment: You haven't shared enough code for us to give you an actual answer. If you want to [edit] your question to include enough code to help you, we'll be glad to do so.